# Windows Audit Policy/Registry Key Command Check To Only Apply On Domain Controllers

Tags: windows, powershell, if-statement, command, domaincontroller

I am trying to craft a command that would run against all of my Windows machines to check if the "Audit Distribution Group Management" audit policy setting is set to "Success and Failure". I would only like to apply this check to Domain Controller servers and for any other server type to echo out something like "NoCheckRequired", is this possible?

I tried to create an if-else statement on PowerShell for this, but it was not successful.

Comment: "I tried to create an if-else statement on PowerShell for this, but it was not successful." - looks like you forgot to post your code

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen, what I tried to do did not work and it was just random test commands. I tried to use the "wmic.exe ComputerSystem get DomainRole" command to find out the type of machine, values 4 / 5 mean DC server from my understanding, and using an IF statement, I tried to match those values and check if the group policy audit settings were set and for any other values returned other than 4 / 5 (ELSE statement) I tried to echo "NoCheckRequired", this was not successful. Can you please help? I am not sure if this is the right approach or if there is an easier way to do this test?

Comment: Seems like you just want someone to write it for you. Please attempt it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to use the "wmic.exe ComputerSystem get DomainRole" command to find out the type of machine, values 4 / 5 mean DC server from my understanding, and using an IF statement, I tried to match those values and check if the group policy audit settings were set and for any other values returned other than 4 / 5

`wmic.exe ComputerSystem get DomainRole` outputs the property name on a separate line before outputting the actual value, so comparing to the number `4` (as an example) will not work.

Instead, use the `Get-CimInstance` cmdlet:

```
$CS = Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem

if($CS.DomainRole -in 4,5){
    # We're on a Domain Controller
}
elseif($CS.DomainRole -in 1,3) {
    # We're on a Domain member
}
else {
    # We're on a workgroup machine
}
```

Comment: you the man, that if/else statement works perfectly! I inserted the missing sections into the statements and with a bit of regex got it to match correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Get-ADComputer -Filter 'primarygroupid -eq "516"'
```

Will filter the Domain controller